# CRON schedule to run a .py file

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, cron

Im trying to follow this [blog](https://www.codementor.io/@gergelykovcs/how-to-run-and-schedule-python-scripts-on-raspberry-pi-n2clhe3kp) about setting up a CRON service to run a .py file every 15 mintes

In the [blog](https://www.codementor.io/@gergelykovcs/how-to-run-and-schedule-python-scripts-on-raspberry-pi-n2clhe3kp) it states to place your .py file in the /home directory and then make sure you can execute the script using `chmod +x script.py`

Opening terminal on the pi `/home/pi/test/script.py` and running `chmod +x script.py` doesn't do anything...

And of course neither does any CRON process. Would anyone have any ideas to try?

This is my script if it makes a difference. It grabs a temperature sensor reading from a BACnet building automation system using `BAC0`.

```
import BAC0
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

print(BAC0.version)

bacnet = BAC0.lite()
data = []

time.sleep(2)

try:


    stuff = {}
    stamp = datetime.now()
    elctricMeterReading = bacnet.read('201:2 analogValue 300 presentValue')
    print(f'elctricMeterReading {elctricMeterReading} kW')
    stuff['Date'] = stamp
    stuff['MeterReading'] = elctricMeterReading

    data.append(stuff)

    master_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    master_data.columns = ['Date', 'MeterReading']

    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///save_pandas.db', echo=True)
    sqlite_connection = engine.connect()
    sqlite_table = "OutsideTemp_MeterReading"
    master_data.to_sql(sqlite_table, sqlite_connection, if_exists='append')
    sqlite_connection.close()
    print("Data saved to sql!")

    time.sleep(2)


except:# bacnet communication fails
    bacnet.disconnect()



bacnet.disconnect()
```

***SCREENSHOT***

In thonny on the pi, if I run the script it works just fine..

[image]

***SCREENSHOT for CRON logs***
`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`
[image]

***Takeway***
`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`
to make sure CRON service is working and have the `shebang` correct!
Final CRON service config:
`*/15 * * * * python3 /home/pi/dataProj/bacNetTest.py` which should be able to run from terminal if not there is a problem. Without the `python3` for some reason CRON defaulted to python2 which threw syntax faults

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.  This is a standard how do I debug a program question.  My first thought would be to add print statements to see where the script stops .

Comment: I added a screenshot... It works just fine if I run it thru Thonny.. The .py file. Any ideas to try?

Comment: Not a Pi problem. If the script won't run in terminal it DEFINITELY won't run in cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing a shebang in the beginning of your python script.
Please write `#!/usr/bin/env python` for python2 or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for python3 as a first line of your .py file. Alternatively you can write your cronjob command as `python /path/to/your/script.py` (or `python3`) to specify directly what to use to run your script.
If you put all the thing together the cronjob should be like this if you want it to run every 15 minutes: `*/15 * * * * python /path/to/your/script.py`.
If your script also outputs something you should install and configure some MTA like `postfix` so  you can read what your script outputs. For more info about cron and postfix see: https://askubuntu.com/a/646831/1095670

Comment: Ah thank you I missed this. I added that into the first line of the .py file. Ill see if it works in the next 15 minutes as I would think the CRON service would be still be trying :)

Comment: So even though the shebang starts with `#` its still used by the program? I thought that character comments out all code

Comment: Shebang is not executed by your python interpreter but it is rather an interpreter directive for your OS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: I added in another screenshot to the post for the CRON service log using the command. It looks like something about no MTA installed discarding output... Any ideas to try?

Comment: to run the CRON service from the command line. `sudo contrab -e` and `15 * * * * sudo /home/pi/dataProj/bacNetTest.py` is the saved service

Comment: mta stands for mail transfer agent. if you want to see the output you have to install e.g. postfix. your crontab also runs as sudo already so `15 * * * * /home/pi/dataProj/bacNetTest.py` is enough. Try to install postfix an read in the log to see what is the output (`sudo tail -f /var/mail/root`)

Comment: Would I add the postfix to the `15 * * * * /home/pi/dataProj/bacNetTest.py sudo tail -f /var/mail/root`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109408/discussion-between-kyjanond-and-henryhub).